# Split images in half vertically and save write them in incremental order: opevcv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a directory with several images named 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and so forth. I want to take each image from this directory split them in half vertically, and save each half of each image  as 1.png, 2.png and so forth.

So, 1.png from input directory should be 1.png and 2.png in path directory.

2.png from input should be 3.png and 4.png.

I want to do this for all images at once.

Currently, I have this:

```
import os
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

path = "clean"
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

for filename in glob.glob('*.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, depth = img.shape
    width_cutoff = width // 2
    s1 = img[:, :width_cutoff]
    s2 = img[:, width_cutoff:]
    cv2.imwrite('{}{}{}'.format(path,'/',os.path.split(filename)[1]), s1)
    cv2.imwrite('{}{}{}'.format(path,'/',os.path.split(filename)[1]), s2)
```

Please help.

Comment: to create path you could use `os.path.join(path, ...)` without `/`

Comment: what is the problem? If you have file `N.png` then you have to create `(2*N-1).png` and `(2*N).png`. So you have to convert filename to integer and calculate new numbers. Or you should use some variable to calculate it `number += 1`. Maybe first check what you create with `{}{}{}'.format(...)` because you create the same path for two files - so you have wrong filenames.

Comment: BTW: system may give filenames in random order so better use `sorted(glob.glob('*.png'))` if you want to use `number += 1`

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve it using your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you want to convert `N.png` to `(2*N-1).png` and `(2*N).png` - so you have to get number from filename, convert to integer and calculate `2*N-1` and `2*N`

```
import os
import cv2
import glob

path = "clean"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

for filename in glob.glob('*.png'):
    
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, depth = img.shape
    width_cutoff = width // 2
    s1 = img[:, :width_cutoff]
    s2 = img[:, width_cutoff:]
    
    number = int(filename.split(".")[0])
    number2 = 2*number
    number1 = number2-1

    cv2.imwrite(f'{path}/{number1}.png', s1)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{path}/{number2}.png', s2)
```